# iOS app crashes randomly because of bad install

Tags: ios, crash, installation

I've had a fairly large app (50mb) in the App Store for several years now with many updates and thousands of users. Before each release I do a lot of testing, analyzing and beta-testing on all sorts of devices and situations before releasing an update.

Every once in a while I get a horrific bug report that says the app is crashing ALL the time and is completely unusable. What seems to fix this EVERY TIME is telling the user to delete the app, power cycle the device and reinstall the app while under wi-fi.

This means to me that under some unknown circumstances to me, my app is being installed badly. And this has been happening through iOS 4, 5, 6 and now 7.

Is this happening to anyone else? Any known causes or fixes besides my reinstall fix?

To make matters worse, this shows up in a few bad reviews that say the app crashes all the time. All the other reviews are 5 stars! I hate getting blamed for a bad install.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you ever look at any crash reports from these issues?

Comment: Are the crashes predominantly happening on older devices or newer devices? Analytical data is the only place to know where to start looking...

Comment: Is it possible the app is taking too long to launch and getting killed? Restarting the device will kill any other processes and may make it fast enough to launch - might not actually be fixed by reinstalling the app.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, but there's no pattern I can see. Old devices, new devices and the crashes happen at completely random places in the app. And when I try to replicate the order of events, nothing. When I ask the user to go through my reinstall steps, they send me the most wonderful thank you email that all is well and it's not crashing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark here, but could it be related to wireless connectivity (ie an API timing out)? Very hard to say without more details.

Comment: I guess anything is possible, but I think my point here (if there is one) is that the actual install process is somehow allowing a flawed install to take place. Obviously this would be an iOS thing, but I'm just wondering if it's happening to anyone else, and if so, if there were any clues.

Comment: I totally understand, these are the hardest of bugs to squash, particularly for solo developers. All I can say is good luck!